# bash file returns unexpected token `$'do\r''

Tags: bash

I found this script online and tried to use it:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Target directory
TARGET=$3
echo "Copying to $TARGET"
for i in $(git diff --name-only $1 $2)
    do
        # First create the target directory, if it doesn't exist.
        mkdir -p "$TARGET/$(dirname $i)"
        # Then copy over the file.
        cp "$i" "$TARGET/$i"
    done
echo "Done";
```

I've validated the script online, and the script is okay. I've also tried to change it in various ways, but it doesn't work for me.

I've also tried running something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Target directory
TARGET=$3
echo "Copying to $TARGET"
for i in $(ls)
do
    echo "text"
done
```

And I still get the same error:

```
./git-copy.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/git-copy.sh: line 6: `do
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your script has been edited on a DOS or Windows based system and contains carriage-return characters that Linux/Unix does not like (that what `\r` is). You could use `dos2unix` to convert the carriage return line endings to the correct format; if you don't have `dos2unix` you might use `awk` like

```
awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' git-copy.sh > git-copy2.sh
mv git-copy2.sh git-copy.sh
```

Answer (score 52):

Another possible solution using unix text editor vi:

open file in vi edit with `vi filename.sh` command;

type in vi `:set ff=unix` command;

save file with `:wq`

It will save the file with unix line endings.

Comment: best and quickest solution ever

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

```
dos2unix my_script.sh
```

If you don't have dos2unix :

For CentOS, Fedora or RHEL:

```
$ sudo yum install dos2unix
```

For Ubuntu or Debian:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tofrodos
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/fromdos /usr/bin/dos2unix
```

## Explanation

This commonly is caused when the executable file is created in an operative system (windows) and used in another operative system (Linux). Also rare text editors could be the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Just change your line sequence in your text editor from CRLF to LF. It worked for me :)

**for notepad++** : `edit => EOL Conversion => Unix(LF)`

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather common nightmare :)

I built a script to normalize  `\r\n` from Dos and from (old)Mac; it also removes BOM
if present:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -pi
s/\012\r|\r\012|\012|\r/\012/g;            ## normalize line endings
s/^(\xFF\xFE|\xFE\xFF|\xEF\xBB\xBF)//;     ## remove common initial BOM
```

Usage: `script textualfile*`

Ok, ok: Choose a better name for it! chmod and install it

Answer (score 3):

I am editing the same thing in the windows system and running in the Linux system . this worked for me.
**for notepad++ : edit => EOL Conversion => Unix(LF)**

Answer (score 1):

I had a case in which a had to write (INSERT) into DB the field that had such a bash script (on Windows's version of Intellij Idea) and then I had to read out the script from DB back on Unix server.
On unix I got this subject's error `$'do\r''` for the reason explained above.

The solution was - copy\paste script on Win into Notepad, change in Notepad unix line endings from Windows (CR LF) to Unix (LF), save it in a file. Open file, copy\paste into Idea's database console. 
Then it worked fine on Unix for the case it was not origin from Unix.

(Idea also has options to choose line endings in its editor)