# Writing bash script to iterate through directories

Tags: xml, bash, cygwin

I have never done any scripting before, so I am completely new to it. I need to run an XSLT translation over multiple files in multiple directories. I am trying to do this on Cygwin.

I currently have a bunch of files (all with the same name, metadata.xml) in different directories. From my current directory, the path is data/Foldername/metadata.xml (with the foldernames being unique).

The pseudocode for this would be:

For all files in /data/Foldername/metadata.xml
xsltproc (metadata.xml in current directory) translation.xslt > (output needs to be foldername the current file is in .rdf)

Comment: https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/find-files-in-linux-using-the-command-line/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=`find ./ -name 'metadata.xml'`
for item in $files
do
  xsltproc $item translation.xslt > ${item%/*}.rdf
done
```

Comment: Pretty much perfect, though I reversed the order of the XML file and the XSLT file, so the last line should be:  xsltproc translation.xslt $item > ${item%/*}.rdf

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
search_dir="Path to data directory"
for item in "$search_dir"/*
do
  xsltproc "$item"/translation.xslt "$item"/metadata.xml > "$item"/"$item".rdf
done
```

this should solve your query...
As you said you will be using Cygwin terminal to excute shell script...so please don't create or edit your script on DOS or Windows based System as it will contains carriage-return characters (i.e. "\r")  that Linux/Unix does not like 
for more info related to this please refer link [bash file returns unexpected token `$'do\r''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176781/bash-file-returns-unexpected-token-do-r)

for **xsltproc** usage you can refer to [link](http://fhoerni.free.fr/comp/xslt.html)