# Docker entrypoint cannot be found

Tags: bash, docker

I'm encountering a strange issue, that I cannot resolve.
I have a `docker-compose.yml`, describing my `server` container:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  server:
      container_name: server
      image: server:latest
      build: server/
      networks:
          - shared-network
      restart: always
networks:
  shared-network:
```

And a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY entrypoint.sh /app/

RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`Dockerfile` obviously points to a file `entrypoint.sh`, which has some scripts that shall run when the container starts.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
/docker-compose.yml
/server (DIR)
/server/Dockerfile
/server/entrypoint.sh (executable)
```

For completeness, the `entrypoint.sh` can be:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
```

Now, when I build the container (running `docker-compose up --build`), everything runs fine until the `ENTRYPOINT`, which gives me the following error:

```
server  | /bin/bash: /app/entrypoint.sh: No such file or directory
```

Note that `COPY` AND `chmod` don't throw any error, which for me indicates that the file is definitely there. I even tried it out. When `chmod` points to a file that's not there, it fails.

Now I'm running out of ideas. Has anyone some suggestions to try out or sees anything I'm missing?

Comment: *when I start the container, everything runs fine until the ENTRYPOINT* you mean when you build the image?

Comment: dcoker inspect image ,and post output here.

Comment: @Paolo yes, exactly. Sorry for the unclearness.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including your entrypoint.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Will add that, but it's not relevant at all for the example, that's why I omitted it.

Comment: @StefanWobbe It is relevant, because when I try to reproduce your issue, it works as expected.

Comment: Run this command : `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash server` and then see if `/app/entrypoint.sh` is there.

Comment: @HansKilian yeah you're right, didn't think about that. It only makes it harder for people to reproduce it, if I omit it. Sorry.
@Philippe Yes, `/app/entrypoint.sh` is there. Runnning `/bin/sh /app/entrypoint.sh` also successfully runs it.

Comment: In your entrypoint you are running `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Oops, sorry, that was a typo. `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` work fine.

Comment: @Philippe Funnily enough, `docker run -it --entrypoint /app/entrypoint.sh` works as expected.

Comment: Indeed. Double check the `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/app/entrypoint.sh"]` in Dockerfile.

Comment: Was the file created in windows and you are running on linux?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176781/bash-file-returns-unexpected-token-do-r/43004720#43004720

Comment: Does `ENTRYPOINT /app/entrypoint.sh` work ?

Comment: @JRichardsz I am working on Linux with vim so that shouldn't be a problem.
@Philippe Doesnt change anything.. Also tried `CMD /app/entrypoint.sh`, same result.

Anyways, for other reasons I am now using volumes and mirroring the folder containing entrypoint.sh into the cotainer. And this did the trick, although it's no real solution to the problem.